# How can I put a "(de)select all" check box in an SWT Table header?

Tags: java, checkbox, swt

I have an SWT Table that I'm instantiating with the `SWT.CHECK` style in order to display a check box next to every row.  My users have requested another check box in the header row of the table in order to allow them to select/deselect all the rows with one click.

I can't see any obvious way to do it, and I've only found Swing/JTable examples through Google.  Does anyone know how to do this?  I'm hoping it's possible without re-implementing Table or falling back on a header context menu.

Answer (score 7):

Just create two images of check box. First one without a tick and second one having a tick.Now add the first image to the tableColumn header. After that add listener to tableColumn in such a way that when you click button for the first time, `table.selectALL()` method should be fired along with changing the tableColumn header image to second one. When you click button again call `table.deSelectAll()` method and replace the tableColumn header with the first image.

You can use this condition:

> When the checkbox(image) is clicked, use a for loop to check whether,
>   any of the checkboxes in the table is checked. if anyone is found
>   checked then fire table.deSelectAll() method , else fire
>   table.selectAll() method.

There will not be any problem for the "checkbox" during table/widow resizing.

```
tableColumn0.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean checkBoxFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getItemCount(); i++) {
            if (table.getItems()[i].getChecked()) {
                checkBoxFlag = true;
            }
        }

        if (checkBoxFlag) {
            for (int m = 0; m < table.getItemCount(); m++) {
                table.getItems()[m].setChecked(false);
                tableColumn0.setImage(new Image(Display.getCurrent(),
                        "images/chkBox.PNG"));

                table.deselectAll();

            }
        } else {
            for (int m = 0; m < table.getItemCount(); m++) {
                table.getItems()[m].setChecked(true);
                tableColumn0.setImage(new Image(Display.getCurrent(),
                        "images/chkBox2.PNG"));

                table.selectAll();
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `FormLayout` to allow stacking objects, then add a checkbox *on top* of the table as follows:

```
FormData fd = new FormData();
fd.left = new FormAttachment(table, 5, SWT.LEFT);
fd.top = new FormAttachment(table, 5, SWT.TOP);
checkbox.setLayoutData(fd);
checkbox.moveAbove(table);
```

You might find it useful for correctly aligning the checkbox to obtain the height of the table header row with `table.getHeaderHeight()`.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response.  I've been meaning to try this out for ages.  Will give it a go and accept if it does what I think it will :)  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Drop a comment if it doesn't work out as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> Fully describe this code :: de)select all” check box in an SWT Table
>   header

---

```
public class TaskView extends ViewPart {

    public static TableItem std_item;
    public static List<Student> std=new ArrayList<Student>();
    public static Table table;
    private TableColumn col_name_add;
    private TableColumn col_image_add;
    static int countcheck;
    static int  staticno=1;
    static int check=0,uncheck=0;

    public TaskView() {
        setTitleImage(ResourceManager.getPluginImage("RCP_Demo", "icons/Tasksview.png"));
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        parent.setLayout(null);

        ////////// Table Create
        table = new Table(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION|SWT.CHECK|SWT.CENTER);
        ////SWT.CHECK: Display first column check box

        table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

                TableItem item = table.getItem(table.getSelectionIndex());
                for(int col=1;col<table.getColumnCount();col++)
                {
                    //Table_Column Checked or Not
                    if(item.getChecked())
                        item.setChecked(false);
                    else
                        item.setChecked(true);

                    /////////First column value get
                    if(col==1)
                    {
                        System.out.println(item.getText(col));
                    }
                    TableItem[] itemCheck = table.getItems();
                    for(int i=0;i<table.getItemCount();i++)
                    {
                        if(itemCheck[i].getChecked())
                            ++check;
                        else
                            ++uncheck;
                    }
                    if(check==table.getItemCount())
                        //Change column image:Checkbox checked
                        col_image_add.setImage(ResourceManager.getPluginImage("RCP_Demo", "icons/check.png"));
                    else
                        //Change column image:Checkbox Unchecked
                        col_image_add.setImage(ResourceManager.getPluginImage("RCP_Demo", "icons/uncheck.png"));

                    //System.out.println("Check:"+check+"uncheck"+uncheck);
                    check=0;
                    uncheck=0;
                }
            }
        });
        table.setBounds(10, 10, 343, 297);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        ////// SWT Table header Column
        col_image_add = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
        col_image_add.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                //All Row selected or Not
                //column Icon change checked(selected) or not

                System.out.println("Total Row Count:"+table.getItemCount());
                TableItem item[] = table.getItems();
                if(staticno==1)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<table.getItemCount();i++)
                    {
                        item[i].setChecked(true);
                        col_image_add.setImage(ResourceManager.getPluginImage("RCP_Demo", "icons/check.png"));
                    }
                    staticno=0;
                }else
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<table.getItemCount();i++)
                    {
                        item[i].setChecked(false);
                        col_image_add.setImage(ResourceManager.getPluginImage("RCP_Demo", "icons/uncheck.png"));
                    }
                    staticno=1;
                }
            }
        }
        });
        col_image_add.setMoveable(true);
        col_image_add.setToolTipText("Click");
        col_image_add.setImage(ResourceManager.getPluginImage("RCP_Demo", "icons/uncheck.png"));
        col_image_add.setWidth(36);

        //Dynamic column Name add

        String[] Col_names={"Stud_id","Stud_Name","Stud_Gender"};
        for(int i=0;i<Col_names.length;i++)
        {
            col_name_add = new TableColumn(table,SWT.CENTER);
            col_name_add.setWidth(100);
            col_name_add.setText(Col_names[i]);
        }
    }
    public TableViewer getViewer() {
          return null;
    }
}
```

thanks....