# How to add buttons to table header?

Tags: java, button, swt

Is it possible to add (three) buttons to the header of a SWT table?

Currently, I have a separate group to select, deselect and toggle the check state of table columns and I'd like to integrate that into the table. Each button should trigger its individual action, so I cannot use a single image as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520958/how-can-i-put-a-deselect-all-check-box-in-an-swt-table-header).

It should somehow look like this:

[image: Buttons in table header]

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334546/combo-in-columnheader-with-swt) might be helpful.

Comment: I managed to draw buttons //above// the table, using a ``FormLayout``. This is the closest I could get so far. However, this solution has a couple of problems, e.g. if columns are moved or resized.

Comment: That's probably as close as you get. You'd have to resize the buttons when the columns resize. The answer I linked to explains how you can do that.

Comment: I'll have a closer look. [This is my current approach.](http://pastebin.com/uwN8BkCW) Still thinking about a legit solution to place a small group of buttons above or at the side of the table, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controls (Combo, Radio, Text) in column header SWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046897/controls-combo-radio-text-in-column-header-swt)