# SWT Table checking box by selecting row or checking the box

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I want to create table of elements with checkboxes in which one could change the state of checkbox by: 1) Clicking on checkbox, 2) Clicking on row. **Unfailingly and fastly.**

I've tried:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(280, 300);
        shell.setText("FooTable");

        Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.CHECK | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL| SWT.H_SCROLL);

        String[] titles = { "Column" };

        for (int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < titles.length; loopIndex++) {
            TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NULL);
            column.setText(titles[loopIndex]);
        }

        for (int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < 5; loopIndex++) {
            TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NULL);
            item.setText("Item " + loopIndex);
        }

        for (int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < titles.length; loopIndex++) {
            table.getColumn(loopIndex).pack();
        }

        table.setBounds(25, 25, 220, 200);

        table.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                if (event.detail == SWT.CHECK) {
                    System.out.println("You checked " + event.item);
                } 
                else {
                    System.out.println("You selected " + event.item);
                    TableItem ti  = (TableItem)event.item;
                    ti.setChecked(!ti.getChecked());
                }
            }
        });

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                    display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
     }
}
```

But with this I've got at least 2 problems:

1) When a row is selected and I click on checbox, the two listeners will at the same time change the state of checkbox, so in the end there is no effect (bad).

2) When I double-click on a row, there again won't be any effect (bad), but when I double-click on checkbox (while row is not selected) I can clearly see checkbox changing it's state twice (good).

So how can I fix this or achieve it in another way?

**Edit**
I solved my problem by using multiple buttons instead of table, in this way

```
Button b = new Button(this, SWT.CHECK | SWT.WRAP);
b.setText("item");
```

But through it all, question remains open.

Answer (score 6):

In order to solve your first problem, you can check if the checked item is also selected and revert the check in this case.

The resulting selection listener would look like this:

```java
table.addListener( SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    if( event.detail == SWT.CHECK ) {
      System.out.println( "You checked " + event.item );
      if( table.indexOf( ( TableItem )event.item ) == table.getSelectionIndex() ) {
        TableItem ti = ( TableItem )event.item;
        ti.setChecked( !ti.getChecked() );
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println( "You selected " + event.item );
      TableItem ti = ( TableItem )event.item;
      ti.setChecked( !ti.getChecked() );
    }
  }
} );
```

To solve the double click issue, you can add a default selection listener that changes the check mark if the item (and not the check box) is double clicked

```java
table.addListener( SWT.DefaultSelection, new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    if( event.detail == SWT.NONE ) {
      TableItem ti = ( TableItem )event.item;
      ti.setChecked( !ti.getChecked() );
    }
  }
} );
```

Apart from the technical issues, I find the handling at least unusual and plain annoying when using the keyboard. Make sure that this behavior is what your users actually expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it's not complete yet. Since now there is a problem with double-clicking on checkbox, whose row is selected - it will change it's state once, not twice.

Comment: Right, I overlooked this case and it seems not possible to solve without timers and maybe other quirks. Take this as a signal to rethink the concept. As I said already, keyboard control is really weird. If you nevertheless want to stick with this behavior and the number of items isn't too big, I recommand to _simulate_ the table with Labels in a ScrolledComposite.

Comment: Thanks, I will think about it. The user is supposed to choose a couple of elements from this list, so I thought it would be easier if he could click on names too.

Answer (score 0):

It works when clicking check box. It returns all selected row.

```
@Inject private AddSelectedItem addSelectedItem; //you can also create instance with new addSelectedItem()

...
table = new Table(shell, SWT.CHECK | SWT.BORDER);
table.addSelectionListener(addSelectedItem);
...
```

Class is created and implements SelectionListener.

```
public class AddSelectedItem implements SelectionListener
{
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) 
    {
        ((/*TypeCast - Your Return Type - YourTypeClass*/) event.item.getData()).switchSelected();
    }
}
```

...

```
public class Test // YourTypeClass
{
    private int a,b;  // These are column variables at the table
    private boolean flag;
    public Test(){ //Constructor
     ...
     this.flag=false;
    }

    public void switchSelected() 
    {
        if (flag == false)
            flag = true;
        else
            flag = false;
    }

}
```

Also, implement arraylist and add your items into the list according to flag value. If it was selected (flag==true), add to the arraylist. Then you can reach every item in your arraylist.

```
List<Test > list = new ArrayList<Test >();
```

To sum up, you should define class with selection flag, then add list according to flag value. Then you can print list (selected items and their values) or write list to the file.

Example:

```
Selection    a      b
---------   ---    ---
checkBox     1      2
checkBox     2      3
..........   ..     ..
```

If checkBox is checked, flag returns true. Add it to the list.

Comment: Which object has a method switchSelected() ? Anyway, this doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot missing part. switchSelected() method  set flag (boolean type) which is defined when your implement <YourTypeClass>  (Your Return Type). Then, you can create ArrayList<YourTypeClass> and add your item to the list. So, you have <YourTypeClass>  list  and you can reach <YourTypeClass> variables that hold attributes of your table (column variables).

Comment: To sum up, you should define class with selection flag, then add list according to flag value.

Comment: And where here is solved problem of checbox and selection listeners changing state of object at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

> SWT Table checking box by selecting row or checking the box

Table Column can add images like checked or unchecked

click column checked to all row can checked 
and 
 click column unchecked to all row can unchecked

---

```
        TableColumn tblclmnNewColumn_1 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
        tblclmnNewColumn_1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

                System.out.println("Total Row Count:"+table.getItemCount());
                TableItem item[] = table.getItems();
                //get all the table items
                for(int i=0;i<table.getItemCount();i++)
                {
                    //Table_Column Checked or Not
                    if(item[i].getChecked())
                    {
                        //table items unchecked
                        item[i].setChecked(false);
                        tblclmnNewColumn_1.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\Icon\\uncheck.png"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //table items checked
                        item[i].setChecked(true);
                        tblclmnNewColumn_1.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\Icon\\check.png"));
                    }
                }


            }
        });
        tblclmnNewColumn_1.setMoveable(true);
        tblclmnNewColumn_1.setToolTipText("All Check");
        tblclmnNewColumn_1.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("D:\\Icon\\uncheck.png"));
        tblclmnNewColumn_1.setWidth(36);
```

Fully describe visit this code :: de)select all” check box in an SWT Table header :
[How can I put a "(de)select all" check box in an SWT Table header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520958/how-can-i-put-a-deselect-all-check-box-in-an-swt-table-header/41740708#41740708)